# What is a regular file?

Tags: permissions, rm

```
$ rm foobar
rm: remove regular file `foobar'?
```

What does it mean for a file to be "regular" and why does `rm` treat such a file as a special case?

Answer (score 9):

#### test command

Any file that passes the test (`-f`) is a regular file:

```
$ test -f afile.zip && echo regular
regular
```

If you look through the man page for `test` you'll see all the various types of files.

#### stat command

You can also check if a file is regular by using the `stat` command:

```
$ stat afile.zip 
  File: `afile.zip'
  Size: 1512        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 10370668    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-11-07 15:52:06.719632792 -0500
Modify: 2013-11-07 15:52:00.949760104 -0500
Change: 2013-11-07 15:52:00.949760104 -0500
```

#### stat() function

To understand more about what the difference is between a regular file and the other possible types take a look at the man page for `stat`. Be sure to look at the man page for the programmers manual and not the man page for the actual `stat` command.

```
$ man 2 stat
```

This section in particular shows the various types of files:

```
   The following flags are defined for the st_mode field:

       S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit fields
       S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
       S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
       S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
       S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
       S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
       S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
       S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
       S_ISUID    0004000   set UID bit
       S_ISGID    0002000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
       S_ISVTX    0001000   sticky bit (see below)
       S_IRWXU    00700     mask for file owner permissions
       S_IRUSR    00400     owner has read permission
       S_IWUSR    00200     owner has write permission
       S_IXUSR    00100     owner has execute permission
       S_IRWXG    00070     mask for group permissions
       S_IRGRP    00040     group has read permission
       S_IWGRP    00020     group has write permission
       S_IXGRP    00010     group has execute permission
       S_IRWXO    00007     mask for permissions for others (not in group)
       S_IROTH    00004     others have read permission
       S_IWOTH    00002     others have write permission
       S_IXOTH    00001     others have execute permission
```

Answer (score 8):

I figure `rm` is an alias, possibly `rm -i`. The "regular" part doesn't mean anything in particular, it only means that it's not a pipe, device, socket or anything other "special".

Comment: Ah, you're right - it's aliased to `rm -i`.

Comment: So it does mean something in particular. Actually it's a very important aspect of the object to be removed ...

Comment: As @alexander said, it means the file is not a symlink, pipe, rand, null, cpu, etc.  Perhaps you have heard the linux philosophy "everything is a text file".  This isn't literally true, but it suggests a dominant operational context where string processing tools can be applied to filesystem elements directly.  In this case, it means that in a more literal fashion.  To see the detection step in isolation, try the command **file**, as in `file /etc/passwd` or `file /dev/null`.